# Remove the footer from site?

Tags: android-studio

I want to receive the site without footer but make the header exist by (I use "web view") . Can any one solve my problem in java language (Android studio)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use loadDataWithBaseURL() method like below:

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
String mUrl=“<your website url>”;

Document document = Jsoup.connect(mUrl).get();
document.getElementsByClass("footer").remove();
WebSettings ws = mWebView.getSettings();
ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(mUrl,document.toString(),"text/html","utf-8","");
```